# This 'Select Case' construct that modifies the select variable is not working

Tags: vb.net, switch-statement

For some reason, my select case is not working. I'm sure it's something stupid. Here is what I have:

```
Private Function getVirtualCommand(ByVal command As String)
    Dim virCommand As String

    Select Case virCommand
        Case command = "A"
            virCommand = VK_A
        Case command = "B"
            virCommand = VK_B
        Case command = "C"
            virCommand = VK_C
        Case Else
            MsgBox("The key command " + command + " is not listed. getVirtualCommand()", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End Select

    Return virCommand
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `Select Case` to check the value of the `virCommand` variable.  `virCommand` will always be `Nothing` since it was just declared and not set to a value yet.  You need to, instead, check the value of the `command` parameter.  Also, you don't need to re-state the variable name in each `Case` statement.  You just need to state the value, for instance:

```
Private Function getVirtualCommand(ByVal command As String) As Integer
    Dim virCommand As Integer

    Select Case command
        Case "A"
            virCommand = VK_A
        Case "B"
            virCommand = VK_B
        Case "C"
            virCommand = VK_C
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("The key command " & command & " is not listed. getVirtualCommand()", "Error")
    End Select

    Return virCommand
End Function
```

Note that I added an `As Integer` to specify the return type for the function.  When you don't specify the return value, it assumes the return type is `Object`.  It's always best to specify a more specific type so that people calling the function know what to expect.  This would not have compiled if you had `Option Strict On`, which I would recommend.

I also changed the `virCommand` variable from a `String` to an `Integer`, since the virtual key constants (e.g. `VK_A`, `VK_B`) are integers.  This also would not have compiled if you had `Option Strict On`.

Also note that I also changed `MsgBox` to `MessageBox.Show`, which is preferred.  `MsgBox` is an old function which is provided, primarily, for backwards compatability with VB6.  You'll notice that I also changed the string concatenation operator from `+` to `&`.  Coming from a C# background, I'm partial to using `+` for concatenation, myself.  But, unless you have `Option Strict On` using the `+` operator for concatenation can be dangerous.  The `&` is safe, even when you have `Option Strict Off`, and it's more specific and self-documenting, so most people prefer using that when in VB.NET.

Comment: When I add the integer instead of string I get an error saying, `Conversion from string to type 'Integer' is not valid.`

Comment: If that's the case, then you must have the virtual key constants (e.g. `VK_A`, `VK_B`) declared as strings.  I assumed that they were integers, since they typically are.  If you really do have them declared as strings, you may want to reconsider that, since it's probably the wrong type.

Comment: They are declared as this: `Private Const VK_A = &H41`

Comment: Well, that's probably not the reason for that conversion error then.  Either way, you should still declare the types on your constants too.  It should be `Private Const VK_A As Integer = &H41`.  So, which line is it that gives the conversion error that you mentioned?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but even with changing them to `Private Const VK_A As Integer = &H41` it still says the same thing. As soon as it hits `Case "A"` it goes to the error message

Comment: On the face of it, that doesn't make sense.  There must be something else wrong.  Please post your modified code as an update to your question and indicate with a comment which line of code is giving the error and the exact wording of the error.

Comment: You figured it out?  Great!  Just out of curiosity, what was the problem?

Comment: For some reason I had `Select Case virCommand` instead of `Select Case command`... Rookie mistake haha

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
Return virCommand
```

with

```
getVirtualCommand = virCommand
```

This is how functions return values in Visual Basic.

More information is in *[[vbscript] How to return value from a function](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/4a5cfa12-b0b6-4ac9-bbef-2d0461461600/vbscript-how-to-return-value-from-a-function)*.

Comment: That is not required though, the `Return` statement in VB.NET works just fine too; returning the name of the function as a variable is a holdover from the VB6 days and is considered not the greatest practice, as someone coming from a C# background would not immediately know that. `Return` more clearly indicates this is an endpoint to the function.

Comment: But when I step through it, if command is equal to `B` when it gets to `B` it just skips over it to `C`, it doesnt set `virCommand = B`, any thought as to why?

Comment: Check the answer from Steven Doggart. Its the right one. 
ps: karl, you are right about vb6, i still work doing vbscript for access and never worked in vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, you need to check for your parameter command:

```
Private Function getVirtualCommand(ByVal command As String) as Integer
    Dim virCommand as Integer
   Select Case command 
        Case "A"
            virCommand = VK_A
        Case "B"
            virCommand = VK_B
        Case "C"
            virCommand = VK_C
        Case Else
            MsgBox("The key command " + command + " is not listed. getVirtualCommand()", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End Select

    Return virCommand
End Function
```

Comment: Also try setting `Option Strict On`, you'll get plenty of warnings (errors probably too). For one, you don't specify any return type of the function, secondly you don't declare `virCommand`. Check the answer of Steven Doggart, it is quite complete.

Comment: @Styxxy Thanks I changed it accordingly. Cheers.